# Is "was" being left out of the following translation before shown because of parallelism?

Tags: grammar, tenses

"If this work could be discovered, it might, he thought, in all probability be restored. Some of the country people were therefore seized, and, inquiry being made of them, the line of the canal was pointed out, and the place shown at which it had been derived from the Nahr-Malcha."

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! If you're asking about whether someone else's writing is grammatically correct, then this question belongs on English.SE. This site is for asking for assistance with your *own* writing.

Comment: [Please don't ask the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539570/has-was-been-left-out-before-shown-because-of-parallelism) Had I known you'd done that, I would have just voted to close the one on Writing.SE instead of migrating it here. I suppose part of the blame's on me for not checking first, but I've now flagged this to be closed as a duplicate of the first version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The exclusion of "was" is actually an example of [Gapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapping), a form of [Elliptical Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).  Ellipsis is almost, but not quite, the *opposite* of [Parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(rhetoric)); Ellipsis means *leaving out* duplicated information, while Parallelism is about deliberately *adding in* duplication for emphasis.

It is possible that you may be inferring Parallelism from the use of both "pointed out" and "shown" - these *are* both phrases with similar meanings, and *can* be used for Parallelism.  However, they are not being used here to support a common noun/verb, to provide synonymous expression of similar concepts, nor even to contrast antithesis.  It also doesn't help that the second clause (*"the place shown at which it had been derived from the Nahr-Malcha"*) contains a lengthy restrictive clause following the verb.  All you have here is a list of information gathered from the questioning.

You *could* adjust the sentence to invoke more parallelism, by connecting both concepts to a single verb (*"...and, inquiry being made of them, they pointed out the line of the canal, and the place at which it had been derived from the Nahr-Malcha"*), but the excessive length of the second phrase makes this *weak* Parallelism